# My IDE is not recognizing HTML commands for my servlet

Tags: java, html, tomcat, servlets

I am learning how to create a servlet that takes HTML code and makes a program in my browser.
This code was supposed to output a simple welcome message in my browser via HTML.  However, My eclipse IDE does not recognize any of the HTML commands in this code.  It says that the imports are not accessible and that the HTTP variables can't be resolved to a type.  I'm using tomcat version 10.0.12 and Java 13 for the code (I also have java 16 but eclipse only gave me the option to use 13).  I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Tomcat several times and adding servlet-api.jar but none of those changed a thing.  I know there's an extra step I'm missing but I can't figure out what it is?

```
import jakarta.servlet.*;
import jakarta.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;

public class WelcomeServlet extends HttpServlet {   
@Override
protected void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, 
                   HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException, IOException  {

   response.setContentType( "text/html" );
   PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
   out.println( "<title>Welcome to Servlets!</title>" ); 
   {...}
   out.println( "</html>" );
   out.close();  // close stream to complete the page
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've messed up your imports. It sounds like you're following a tutorial that's 20+ years old, a lot of what you're doing is *extremely* outdated. The web is a fairly fast moving environment; I *strenously* advise against using such old tutorials.

The correct import is `import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;`.

Some notes on what you're doing that are bad ideas:

- Star imports aren't advised; it's a bit too easy to get confused about where things live or which type(s) you are fetching from where. Your IDE manages your imports for you; let it.
- You don't want to write HTML inside strings inside your code. Use a templating engine such as Freemarker, Velocity, Thymeleaf, or Google Closure Templates. Alternatively, write static HTML with a ton of javascript (probably with a client-side javascript-based framework) and write your server as an API that doesn't 'answer' in terms of HTML files; it answers in terms of some structured data format such as JSON. Your static (as in, unchanging; any file-serving HTTP service can provide them) HTML+CSS+Javascript does the job of calling your API to get this structured data, and then your HTML+CSS+JavaScript does the job of rendering it into HTML.
- Raw servlets is outdated; the API is extremely old and it shows, for example, you can't even use a simple for-each loop to iterate over all parameter names, because the API returns the obsolete Enumeration instead of the more modern Iterator or even Stream. You neither get the benefit of storing intermediate state in fields (because you aren't guaranteed one instance per invocation), but you also don't get to just dump it all in static fields either (as the spec doesn't guarantee that there'll only ever be one instance) - the worst of both worlds. Look into JAX-RS, Jersey, Dropwizard, sparkjava, or other such frameworks.

Comment: *The correct import is import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;.* OP is targeting Tomcat 10 not 9 or older.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Your project lacks a JAR containing the definition of the Jakarta Servlet API (a set of [interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_(Java))).

Add `jakarta.servlet-api` as a dependency to your project, to present to your IDE the needed JAR file during development but omitted from your final build’s WAR file.

## Details

Your `import` statements refer to the [Jakarta Servlet](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/) API. That [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/API) is not built into Java. So you must make a Servlet API [JAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)) file available to your [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) while developing.

Typically in Java development we use a tool such as [Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) or [Gradle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradle) to assist our IDE in obtaining external dependencies such as the Servlet API JAR.

If you are using Maven, edit your [POM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven#Project_Object_Model) file to specify a dependency for the Servlet API JAR published as part of the [Jakarta.ee](https://jakarta.ee/) project, by the Eclipse Foundation.

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.servlet/jakarta.servlet-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Notice the `scope` element, with a value of `provided`. This means the JAR file should be downloaded, made available to your IDE while developing, but should *not* be copied into your resulting product when you build.

The output of your build will typically be a [WAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_(file_format)) file (not JAR). The `provided` scope means we do *not* want a copy of the Servlet API JAR within that WAR. The reason is that when developing Jakarta EE web apps, we expect to deploy to a compliant application server that carries its own copy of the Servlet API. Every “profile” of Jakarta EE compliant servers are required to include an implementation of the Servlet API.

So your POM will look something like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns = "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation = "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>work.basil.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.servlet/jakarta.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And here is the source code for a simple servlet.

```java
package work.basil.example.demo;

import java.io.*;

import jakarta.servlet.http.*;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.*;

@WebServlet ( name = "helloServlet", value = "/hello-servlet" )
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    private String message;

    public void init ( )
    {
        message = "Hello World!";
    }

    public void doGet ( HttpServletRequest request , HttpServletResponse response ) throws IOException
    {
        response.setContentType( "text/html" );

        // Hello
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println( "<html><body>" );
        out.println( "<h1>" + message + "</h1>" );
        out.println( "</body></html>" );
    }

    public void destroy ( )
    {
    }
}
```

You said:

> I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Tomcat several times

Completely unrelated to your problem, I expect.

The installation of Tomcat comes with an *implementation* of the Servlet API. But your IDE does not “see” Tomcat during development. Your IDE needs to see the [interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_(Java)) defined in the Servlet API.

Your IDE does not actually execute your servlet, so it does not need an implementation, it needs only the interfaces. When you run your Servlet from the IDE, Tomcat is invoked *externally* from the IDE. The IDE attaches a debugger connection to Tomcat to facilitate interactive debugging, but the IDE and Tomcat are actually running as separate distinct processes on the host OS. And as I said, Tomcat comes bundled with its own implementation of those interfaces, so your servlet is able to execute.

---

You said you are using Java 13. Be aware that Java 13 is no longer supported. You should move to either the latest version of Java (17, as of 2021-11), or to one of the [Long-Term Support (LTS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_support) versions (8, 11, 17).

If using Java 11 or 17 rather than 8, I would suggest using Tomcat 10.1.x rather than Tomcat 10.0.x. Tomcat 10.1.x supports Jakarta EE 9.1 and 10, which supports Java 11 and later versus Java 8.

See the [Tomcat version comparison page](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html).

Comment: Ok so I made a new project that runs on 17 on eclipse but I'm not seeing ```jakarta-servlet.api``` jar file in neither Tomcat 10 nor 10.1.  Also, I'm having issues accessing "http://localhost8080" since it just takes me to a dead link.  I've tried "http://128.0.0.1" as well

Comment: @mariosegale (A) As I said in the Answer, Tomcat does not have the API, it has its own *implementation* of the API. Perhaps you should study more about [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/642706). Jakarta.ee defines interfaces, vendors implement. (B) `localhost8080` is not a valid address. You need a COLON character separating the host name from the port: `localhost:8080`. (C) When using loopback address `127.0.0.1`, you need to append the port when using a port number other than the default of 80: `127.0.0.1:8080`. Notice the COLON character.